# In #!/bin/bash. Unix command to get date of the first of a weekday in a month

Tags: shell, date

I'm looking for a straight Unix commands to get first Sunday of next month,  first Monday of next month, first Tuesday of next month, first Wednesday of next month etc.

1. I will need them in the complete date format ( time is not mandatory )
2. I can get numbers like 2, 3, 4 etc. As I don't want only numbers, I will need them in date format (includes day, month, year)

   ```
   $ NEXT_MONTH=`date +'%m %Y' -d 'next month'`
   $ echo $NEXT_MONTH
   04 2017

   $ NEXT_SUNDAY=`cal $NEXT_MONTH | awk 'NF==7 && !/^Su/{print $1;exit}'`
   $ echo $NEXT_SUNDAY
   2
   ```
3. I will need these dates to send notifications for the email group.

Ex: I could get the first Saturday of next month as below.

```
$ firstofmonth=$(date -d '+1 months' '+%Y%m01')
20170401

$ firstsaturday=$(date -d "$firstofmonth" '+%Y-%m')-$((7 - \
                $(date -d "$firstofmonth" '+%u')     ))    
2017-04-1
```

Answer (score 12):

In `ksh93`:

```
$ printf '%(%F)T\n' 'next month, first Monday'
2017-04-03
```

`bash`, since 4.2 now supports a `%(<format>)T` in its `printf` buitin, but not the ability to parse this kind of date expression.

If you had to use `bash` and wanted to use that `%(<format>)T`, you could still do it without forking with something like:

```
printf -v code '%(
  t=$((%s + (12 - %-H) * 60 * 60))
  increment=$((8 - %u))
  current_month=%m)T' -1
eval "$code"
until
  t=$((t + increment * 24 * 60 * 60)) # next Monday around mid-day
  printf -v code '%(date=%F month=%m)T' "$t"
  eval "$code"
  [ "$month" != "$current_month" ] # until be get to next month
do
  increment=7 # the first increment is the number of days
              # til Monday. Next increments are just a week.
done
echo "$date"
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash . I'm getting the below error in bash                                                                                                                                                                       $ printf '%(%F)T\n' 'next month, first Monday'
-bash: printf: `(': invalid format character

Comment: @Hima, I did say _in ksh93_. `bash` is an unfinished clone of ksh (with some features of (t)csh and zsh and even a few of its own). Recent versions of `bash` have added support for `printf '%(format)T'` from `ksh93`, but not the ability to parse this kind of date specifications. Replace your she-bang with `#! /path/to/ksh93 -`.

Comment: "`bash` is an unfinished clone of ksh" -- I have always felt that way.

Comment: @Stephene, I tried with below command to get next month last saturday                                                                                                          $ cal 04 2017 | awk 'NF <= 7 { print $6 }' | grep -v "^$" | tail -1
28  It displays the number 28, but I'm looking for the complete date 04/28/2017, plz suggestm if it possible with it.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming GNU `date` (for that `-d` you're using yourself), and a `zsh`-like shell for `{1..7}`:

```
$ for i in {1..7} ; do \
    LC_ALL=C date '+%Y-%m-%d %a' -d "$(date +%Y%m0${i}) next month" ; \
  done | awk '/Mon/ {print $1}'
2017-04-03
```

Replace the `awk` <kbd>Mon</kbd> with whatever weekday is required (use `LC_ALL=C` to get English month names regardless of the user's locale). Also, might be better to store this into a variable if you will be re-querying for each day of the week:

```
$ days=$(for i in {1..7} ; do \
           LC_ALL=C date '+%Y-%m-%d %a' -d "$(date +%Y%m0${i}) next month" ; \
         done)

$ for i in Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun ; do \
    echo "${days}" | awk "/${i}/"'{print $1}' ; \
  done
2017-04-03
2017-04-04
2017-04-05
2017-04-06
2017-04-07
2017-04-01
2017-04-02
```

Comment: In bash also, this code returns the next month first Sun, Mon, Wed, Thus, Fri, Sat. Thank you.                                                                                      I think, I can modify this command to get next month last Sun, Mon, Wed etc. Let me try this.

Comment: Hi, I tried the below command to get next month last saturday                      $ cal 04 2017 | awk 'NF <= 7 { print $6 }' | grep -v "^$" | tail -1                                                                                                                                   It displays the number 28, but I'm looking for the complete date like 04/28/2017, plz suggest if it possible.

Comment: " for i in {1..7}; do date '+%Y-%m-%d %a' -d "$(date +%Y%m01 -d '2 months') ${i} days ago"; done | awk '/Sat/ {print $1}' " - this will give 2017-04-29, which is the last Saturday of the next month.

This code goes 2 months forward, to the first day of that month, and then goes back 1-7 days to get the last 7 days day data for the previous month.

I would personally avoid using cal as I have tried the other examples here and none work at all on my version (CentOS 6).

Answer (score 2):

PHP actually makes it pretty easy to parse dates with textual input, if it's available on your system.

Example:

```
bash-[522]$ php -qr 'date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); echo date("d-m-Y\n", strtotime("first monday of next month"));'
03-04-2017
```

I have this function in my .bashrc:

```
get_date ()
{
    text="$*";
    php -qr "date_default_timezone_set(\"UTC\"); echo date(\"d-m-Y\n\", strtotime(\"$text\"));"
}
```

Which I can use as:

```
bash-[523]$ get_date first monday of next month
03-04-2017
```

---

**Edit** Adding option to use `cal`

Almost every system that has `bash` will have `cal`.  The calendar program.  You can get a list of the date for the first of each week day by running a combination of `cal`, `date`, and `awk`, as follows:

```
 cal -hN $(date -d 'next month' +%b' '%Y) | grep -v $(date -d 'next month' +%b) | awk -v date=$(date -d 'next month' +%Y-%m-) '{ printf "%s: "date"%02i\n", $1, $2; }'
```

Which will give you the following output:

```
Su: 2017-04-02
Mo: 2017-04-03
Tu: 2017-04-04
We: 2017-04-05
Th: 2017-04-06
Fr: 2017-04-07
Sa: 2017-04-01
```

Change `$2` to `$NF` in the awk statement to get the date of the last occurence of each day in a month.

Comment: Its not working in bash, $ php -qr 'date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); echo date("d-m-Y\n", strtotime("first monday of next month"));'
-bash: php: command not found. please let me know the way to get it done in bash as well. and also, the command to get next month last Sun thru Sat. I did tried it, some how it throws errors. thanks ..!!

Comment: The means you don't have `php` installed.  I have updated with an example that uses the `cal`, `date`, and `awk` commands.

Comment: I tried this command and throws an error.  Thank you.!!                                                                    $ cal -hN $(date -d 'next month' +%b' '%Y) | grep -v $(date -d 'next month' +%b) | awk -v date=$(date -d 'next month' +%Y-%m-) '{ printf "%s: "date"%02i\n", $1, $2; }'
cal: invalid option -- h
usage: cal [-13smjyV] [[month] year]

Answer (score 0):

You can just list all days in a next month with weekdays:

```
# for i in `seq 1 93`; do date '+%Y-%m-%d %w' -d "+$((i - 31)) days"; done | sed 's|0$|7|g' | grep `date +"%Y-%m" --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) 1 month"`
2021-02-01 1
2021-02-02 2
2021-02-03 3
2021-02-04 4
2021-02-05 5
2021-02-06 6
2021-02-07 7
2021-02-08 1
2021-02-09 2
2021-02-10 3
2021-02-11 4
2021-02-12 5
2021-02-13 6
2021-02-14 7
2021-02-15 1
2021-02-16 2
2021-02-17 3
2021-02-18 4
2021-02-19 5
2021-02-20 6
2021-02-21 7
2021-02-22 1
2021-02-23 2
2021-02-24 3
2021-02-25 4
2021-02-26 5
2021-02-27 6
2021-02-28 7
```

Append this to get first Sunday of the month:  `| grep 7$ | head -n 1`

That's it

---

Off topic: get last Friday of the month:  `| grep 5$ | tail -n 1`

Off topic: get something for this month, change `1 month` to `0 month`